# How do I create a binary vector based on N percentile?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

How do I create a binary vector (named as `group`) for patients where the upper 25% gene expression is coded as 1 and all other patients are coded as 0?

```
> dput(head(dat, 20))
c(14.0217647549219, 4.38634192539018, 11.230612647966, 13.5882888840484, 
10.2699597878478, 8.09562488203986, 14.1224780341231, 10.4488388145038, 
12.2745444001468, 9.09203349810451, 14.3513862469323, 11.5782968747535, 
13.6411144041398, 9.79892114560863, 11.1019611651618, 12.5146158084875, 
12.643970834391, 1.09720624597437, 5.83979838350692, 11.1604484254692
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `quantile` to create the group

```
dat$group <- with(dat, +(V1 >= quantile(V1, 0.75)))
dat$group
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, OP's 'dat' is a `vector`

```
dat <-  c(14.0217647549219, 4.38634192539018, 11.230612647966, 13.5882888840484, 10.2699597878478, 8.09562488203986, 14.1224780341231, 10.4488388145038, 12.2745444001468, 9.09203349810451, 14.3513862469323, 11.5782968747535, 13.6411144041398, 9.79892114560863, 11.1019611651618, 12.5146158084875, 12.643970834391, 1.09720624597437, 5.83979838350692, 11.1604484254692 )
```

Therefore, we can directly apply the `quantile` on the object

```
group <- +(dat >= quantile(dat, 0.75))
out <- data.frame(V1 = dat, group)
```

-ouptut

```
 out
          V1 group
1  14.021765     1
2   4.386342     0
3  11.230613     0
4  13.588289     1
5  10.269960     0
6   8.095625     0
7  14.122478     1
8  10.448839     0
9  12.274544     0
10  9.092033     0
11 14.351386     1
12 11.578297     0
13 13.641114     1
14  9.798921     0
15 11.101961     0
16 12.514616     0
17 12.643971     0
18  1.097206     0
19  5.839798     0
20 11.160448     0
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(4.124, 5.215, 1.368, 0.325, 0.368, 3.653, 
36.12, 0.124)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: I have a large dataset. How do I create the data frame?

Comment: @melil Sorry, I didn't understand your question.  Why do you need to create the dataframe?  You already provided an example, and the  code with `quantile` can work on vectors, i.e. columns extracted.

Comment: @melil Did you meant you have some file and you want to read the data?  In that you can use `dat <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean the `dat <- structure(...)` part of your answer.

Comment: @melil that is just using `dput(dat)` It gives the structure of the data so that if you copy the code in the post and execute we wll have the same data struvture.  Normally, when people show their data (as you had shown), there could be some issues i.e. may be your data columns have different types and some code won't work.  With `dput`, either you or me or anybody can use the same data with same class structure

Comment: Ok thanks. I wasn't able to use `dput` because the file is too large and the dput gets truncated.

Comment: > dat$group <- with(dat, +(V1 >= quantile(V1, 0.75)))
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Comment: @melil Can you show `dput(head(dat, 20))`

Comment: @melil This error happens if you don't have a data.frame.  Is it a `vector` or `matrix`

Comment: > dput(head(dat, 20))
c(14.0217647549219, 4.38634192539018, 11.230612647966, 13.5882888840484, 
10.2699597878478, 8.09562488203986, 14.1224780341231, 10.4488388145038, 
12.2745444001468, 9.09203349810451, 14.3513862469323, 11.5782968747535, 
13.6411144041398, 9.79892114560863, 11.1019611651618, 12.5146158084875, 
12.643970834391, 1.09720624597437, 5.83979838350692, 11.1604484254692
)

Comment: Thank you. That works. What's the `+` sign at `+(dat...)`? Is `out` the output variable? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @melil it is to coerce the logical to binary i.e. TRUE ->1 and FALSE -> 0

Comment: How do I assign names to the two groups?

Comment: @melil What kind of names you need.  Can you be more specific.  Do you need `factor(group, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))`

Comment: @melil in the above code, just change 'No', 'Yes' to 'bad', 'good'

Comment: names(group) <- factor(group, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Good", "Bad"))

Comment: @melil If it names, then do `names(group) <-  as.character(factor(group, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Good", "Bad")))`

Comment: @melil or just `names(group) <- c("Bad", "Good")[1 + group]`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I now want to create a data matrix by combining this group variable with all the variables in another annotation file. I then want to run a Kaplan-Meier analysis to determine if a difference exists between the two groups, i.e., `good` and `bad`.

Comment: @melil can you post as a new question as it is not clear to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479962/how-do-i-run-a-kaplan-meier-km-analysis-to-determine-any-difference-in-surviva